# How generate the Renderer from a Maui element

Tags: custom-controls, maui, renderer

I have a application where I need to extract the renderer from a Xamarin forms element, this is working fine Xamarin forms, I'm not sure how we can achieve this in MAUI, any inputs would be deeply appreciated. I'm doing this in renderer

```
 public AView ConvertFormsToNative(Xamarin.Forms.View view, Rectangle size)
        {
            var vRenderer = Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(view, this.Context);
            var viewGroup = vRenderer.View;
            vRenderer.Tracker.UpdateLayout();
            var layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height);
            viewGroup.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
            view.Layout(size);
            viewGroup.Layout(0, 0, (int)view.WidthRequest, (int)view.HeightRequest);
            return viewGroup;
        }
```

This specific line is helping me get the renderer from the forms element

```
var vRenderer = Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(view, this.Context);
```

Any inputs would be really helpfull

Comment: In Maui, we use handlers to augment the appearance and behavior of a cross-platform control beyond the customization. For more details, you can refer to [Customize controls with handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT thanks a lot for the reply, I did take a look into it but haven't researched enough to determine what I need to do can be done by handlers and mappers, what I specifically need to do is  my forms element which has all the configuration to give me a native rendered control of it, which I was able to do with Platform.GetRenderedelement before, anything of that sorts is it provided by MAUI?

Comment: I think you can get the `Renderer` via `var renderer=Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(element, _context);` in MAUI.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. You can go through this [source code docs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/174/files/1a3c6036cd499cd2cec30306c312bc8eecd0ecfd) to see if it can shed some light to you. If it doesn't, you can also create to a [new discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions) in Github.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT The above answer helped, thanks a lot, sorry about the earlier post

Comment: Yes please, you can convert it to a post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Renderer via below code:

`var renderer=Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(element, _context);`

For more details, you can refer to [maui code docs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/174/files/1a3c6036cd499cd2cec30306c312bc8eecd0ecfd);